# Rails: Prevent XSS when using link_to with model attribute given to href

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, href, xss, link-to

Considering the following link_to example:

`link_to "Personal Website", @user.website`

How can I protect it against XSS attack. 
User table is in an external DB, so I cannot trust it. I have tried different approaches using sanitize and h but when I replace in my local DB user website by `javascript:alert('XSS')`, javascript is still being executed when I click on the link.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove "javascript:" in the controller. That's ugly but works, with some caveats (browsers are awesome in what exactly they may accept as "javascript:"). This is not a very strong control.

You can add "http://" (or "https://") statically to the link href, and strip that from your user input. As "javascript:" only works if it's at the first character of an href, statically adding http:// as the beginning mitigates XSS.

You can also use the `Content-Security-Policy` [header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Headers_Project#Content-Security-Policy) to prevent inline Javascript from being run. This has implications on how you can structure your code, and is not supported in all browsers, but when it *is* suported, it's an excellent control.

As always, implementing multiple layers of defense (multiple of the above) will make your application more robust and secure against attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My work around is your first suggestion. I am using brakeman and it is warning about a `unsafe model attribute in link_to href`. So I used a `get_user_url` method in my helper where I handle necessary controls. Brakeman is not warning about XSS attack anymore and at least `javascript:` is not being executed. But as you said it is a bit ugly, that's why I thought there might be a more elegant rails way of doing it. Thanks btw for the `Content-Security-Policy` suggestion. I took my time to dig a bit more about HTTP response header and that was instructive.

Comment: instead of modifying data, you can also do the following: `@user.website.start_with("http") ? link_to("Personal Website", @user.website) : @user.website`